# How to check if JSON is null in swift?

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift

I am currently working on an app which brings back json, in the following format

> "location_subtype" = "somevalue";
>       "location_type" = Force;
>       month = "2015-01";
>       "outcome_status" =     {
>           category = "somevalue";
>           date = "somevalue";
>       };

if the "outcome_status" has value it shows category and date however if the "outcome_value" does not have any value(which is in most of the cases) it is shown as below

> "location_subtype" = "somevalue";
>       "location_type" = Force;
>       month = "2015-01";
>       "outcome_status" = "";
>       "persistent_id" = "";

The question is how can i check if the value for outcome_status is not "null"?

i have tried the following to store the category and date into label but it runs into error, the first if statement should check if the value is not null and if it is not go to next if statement. However it continues to next if statement and i get the following error

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x102089600)

```
if (dict["outcome_status"] != nil)
        {
            if ((dict["outcome_status"]as NSDictionary)["category"] != nil)
            {
                outcomeStatusLabel.text = ((dict["outcome_status"]as NSDictionary)["category"] as NSString)
                outcomeStatusLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0);
                outcomeStatusLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            }

            if ((dict["outcome_status"]as NSDictionary)["date"] != nil)
            {
                outcomeDateLabel.text = ((dict["outcome_status"]as NSDictionary)["date"] as NSString)
                outcomeDateLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0);
                outcomeDateLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            }
        }
```

If i remove the 1st if statement it only crashes when "outcome_status" = "null" and works perfectly fine if there some value in "outcome_status"

What do i need to do so it stops at 1st if statement if the value is = null?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @MartinR if i try the following `if (dict["outcome_status"] as NSString != "")` it still crashes.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try something like this:

Swift code:

```
if let outcome = dict["outcome_status"] as? NSDictionary {
    //Now you know that you received a dictionary(another json doc) and is not 'nil'
    //'outcome' is only valid inside this if statement

    if let category = outcome["category"] as? String {
        //Here you received string 'category'
        outcomeStatusLabel.text = category
        outcomeStatusLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)
        outcomeStatusLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    }

    if let date = outcome["date"] as? String {
        //Here you received string 'date'
        outcomeDateLabel.text = date
        outcomeDateLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)
        outcomeDateLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    }
}
```

This is a safe way to work with Json.

Comment: Thank you, this works brilliantly, the app does not crash now.

Comment: Awesome ... I hadn't been handling sad paths at all and my apps were crashing on sad path :/

Comment: This example works with strings... but with other type doesn´t work. I think the best solution is @NunoFerro http://stackoverflow.com/a/37468020/4693765

Comment: @JosePoseS You need pay attention into the code, there is a type cast operator (`as?`) that will try change json content to be a string (if not return `nil`), said that, if your json content is not a string you need change the type.

Comment: @Vagner You need pay more attention to title question. "How to check if Json is null in swift?" not if is string or other type. I up vote too because is not wrong at all.

Comment: @JosePoseS Yeah, you are right... but not so right... You just need to see beyond the question title. I came here not to exactly answer the question "literary", but I'm here to help people to solve their problems. Cleary in the question body the OP needs 2 things, 1 - check if key exists, 2 - cast content to a specific type, `if let` statement can accomplish that

Answer (score 17):

```
if ((nullObject as? NSNull) == nil)  {
        ...
       }
```

Answer (score 10):

in case you are using Alamofire and JSONSubscriptType use this:

```
if !(parsedJSON["someKey"] == JSON.null) {
//do your stuff 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try corresponding Swift class to following Objective C class,

```
dict["outcome_status"] != [NSNull null]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SwiftyJSON, just check .isEmpty() on the object to confirm if it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can check json is null or not like this

```
if let data = response["data"].dictionary {
    // do something
}
else {
    // do something
}
```